# Please tell me if i can use this song and it's title in my promotional film?

Tags: copyright

I am making a film promoting a health product. I want to use the words "eat, sleep, rave" as screened text throughout the film. This is the name of a Fat boy slim song. I also want to know if I can use this remix of the song as background music. It holds a creative commons license. But I am very ignorant towards copyright laws and what I can and can't do. Obviously the product is not related to the song, other than its use for rejuvenation after a late night. Here is the link to the creative common's remix. https://soundcloud.com/riotten/eat-sleep...

Here is a link to the old promotional video-

Answer (score 2):

For this, you'll really need to see a lawyer to determine if the original re-mix has sufficient rights to the song to place their remix under Creative Commons in the first place.

If they do, then it depends what Creative Commons license they used.  As long as it allows commercial usage (not a NC license) then you would be ok as long as you followed the rest of the terms of the applicable Creative Commons license.  (For example, you would need to post the video under the same type of Creative Common's license.)

Comment: I agree. Also, I remember hearing that in addition to a "commercial use" license, there's another type of license that allows you to promote another product or service. Like using background music in a YouTube video is one thing, but using background music in a commercial for your product is another.

Comment: @BrettFromLA - do you know if that was a CC license?  I'm not aware of anything more specific than the NC option on the CC license.  There are some other licenses that allow more granularity though.

Comment: I might be thinking of the licenses offered by AudioMicro.com. I can't remember where I've seen that. (I use others' music in my YouTube videos when I don't have time to compose it myself.)